# Request ajax no synchronous

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube-api, synchronization

i'l truly sorry for my bad english at first.

I do not know if my problem comes of it, but, when I browse my program in the debugger, I have the impression that my "for" is forgot and it passes has the continuation.

My Code:

```
var nextToken = 50/maxResults;
    urlToken=url;
    for(var k=0;k<nextToken;k++)
    {
        var newToken;

        $.ajax({
            url:urlToken,
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                    $tokenD = data;
                    newToken = data.nextPageToken;
                });
              }
            });

        urlToken = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?pageToken="+newToken+"&part=snippet&playlistId="+playlistId+"&key="+key+"&maxResults="+maxResults+"";
    }

    url = urlToken;

    $('div#container').empty();
```

So in this code, in the debugger, i arrived to "$('div#container').empty();" before the for was finished. I don't know if my problem comes of the ajax request but i don't think so.

If you have any idea =).

Comment: did you check your maxResults value ? if this value is over 50 nextToken will be 0

Comment: Yes I have the expected values. I displays 16 results per page so from the fourth page I need the following token as more result = 50.

Comment: I resolve my problem by removing the JSON request because it's absurd to do the same request getjson avec ajax.